# Which shebang line should I use?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

There are scripts in my project that run fine without the first line (like `#!/bin/`) – without any interpreter path.

So these scripts are running fine, in some cases they fail, but when they run – they execute fine.

I need to modify and put a shell interpreter as the first line.

The problem here is that some scripts fail when I use `#!/bin/ksh` while others fail when I use `#!/bin/bash`.

Can anyone tell me when to use which option?

How can I make sure they will work fine, any other way to generalize and make the interpreter common for all the scripts?

Comment: Use whichever one your script is written for. If you use ksh syntax, use `/bin/ksh`. If you use bash syntax, use `/bin/bash`. If you don't know the differences... well, you need to learn them. It's like asking how to run all Python scripts without knowing if they're written for Python 2 or Python 3 -- they're related languages, with some common ground between them, but incompatible ones nonetheless.

Comment: See [Choose Your Shell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Choose_Your_Shell)

Comment: Do you mean that you literally have just `#!/bin/` on the first line? If not, please clarify the first sentence of your question.

Comment: Thanks Charles! You're right, I need to learn the differences between the different types of shells and their specific syntax.
Do you suggest any website or any link where I can clarify this and make sure my script's syntax is written in which specific shell?
Then I could use that interpreter. Thanks so much.

Comment: For bash, the two resources I most strongly recommend are [the Bash Hackers' Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/) and the Wooledge wiki -- wherein the section most useful to a newcomer is the [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) (but be sure to also see the [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) and [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)).

Answer (score 2):

Each script is written in a certain programming language - bash, ksh, zsh, python, Perl .... You can't for instance write a Python program and hope that Perl can run it. Similarily, a ksh program needs to be executed by ksh, a bash program by bash.

Now, since bash, ksh, zsh and Posix shell **do** have common subset, it is possible to execute it with any of these command processors. If - and only if! - you are sure that this applies to these scripts, I would propose to use Posix shell, because this is the most restrictive one.

But if people designate a script as bash, or as ksh, or what else, the maintainer of the script might sooner or later use features which are particular to only one of this shell languages. Of course you could require that everyone is programming in, say, ksh, but this is a political question, not technical one.

Comment: Generally, this is spot on. One point of exception, though: zsh is **not** a superset of POSIX sh, unless you're either (1) running it under the `sh` name to enable POSIX compatibility mode, or (2) restricting not only the code, but the data being processed (to avoid cases where unquoted expansion behaviors differ). (bash isn't quite a POSIX superset either, the primary place where it's out-of-compliance being its `echo` command illegally supporting `-e`).

Comment: I never claimed that zsh would be a superset of Posix. I said that there is a common subset between those. Mathematically speaking, there exists a set of programs which, when executed under zsh, bash, ksh and Posix, would produce the same result. Not every Posix program would produce the same result in zsh. Some (much fewer) would even not produce the same result on bash or ksh. But if one can't decide on a single language, starting with strict Posix compatibility gives you the best chances that your program will also run in one of the others.

Comment: It's a pretty unreasonably small common subset when you can't even use `$foo` (or any other unquoted variable expansion) without it having two different meanings.

Comment: Yes, I fully agree, but it is pretty unreasonable too to require that a bunch of arbitrary shell scripts is written first without any special shell in mind, and then hope that they will run unmodified under several script processors, as the OP asked. However, it is possible if you really know what you are doing. Quoting every variable, as you pointed out, is a first step. However, the subset you have to restrict yourself, is so small that it is not really fun using it....

Comment: @user1934428
very nicely explained that feature belonging to ksh will only run in ksh and not in bash or vice versa. I completely get that.
Can somebody share the differences between these two? What different commands, different keywords are in each of these interpreter.

Comment: The full list of differences will likely depend on which ksh- and which bash-version you are comparing.  Some you can find with Google, for instance [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771368/difference-between-bash-shell-and-ksh-shell-by-using-while-with-read-what-can), but IMO it's not worth researching this into deep detail. If you write a program, you define the programming language to be used. BTW, you don't need a `#!` line in your script, but have then to tell your users, that you have to specify the shell explicitly, i.e. `bash YOURSCRIPT`.

Answer (score 0):

Whether to use `bash` or `ksh` is a matter of opinion. However, when the `#!` is missing, the default shell of `/bin/sh` is used (or, I thought, is *supposed* to; `bash` appears to execute the script with `bash`.), and how that shell works is defined by the POSIX standard. If you write shell code that conforms to that standard, you can execute it with *any* POSIX-compatible shell (`bash`, `ksh`, `dash`, etc.) and expect the same results in each case.

If you choose to use features that are specific to a given shell, then you need to ensure that your script is executed with that shell. A script that uses features specific to `ksh` will not run correctly, e.g., under `bash`

Comment: This isn't quite right -- if there's no shebang (`#!`) line, what happens will depend on exactly how it's run. If it's run from a bash shell (incl another script running under bash), it'll be run with bash; if it's run from ksh, it'll be run with ksh; if it's run from something like cron, it'll run under /bin/sh. I suspect this is why these scripts sometimes work and sometimes fail.

Comment: "However, when the #! is missing, the default shell of /bin/sh is used" This is not correct. Without the shebang line, you need to specifically invoke an executable to interpret the script through stdin.

Comment: @JoshuaRLi No, you don't. The shebang is used to select an *alternative* to the system shell; it is not required.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I was assuming the OP is executing the script directly; if he is using an explicit interpreter, the shebang doesn't matter.

Comment: @JoshuaRLi : This is not necessarily correct. The calling shell treats the first two characters as *magic number*, from which it tries to derive how to process the file. If this doesn't happen to be a valid magic number (which is likely, but not necessarily the case if you have a text file without #!), the effect depends on the calling shell. I tried it with bash and with Zsh: My version of bash runs such a script as bash, while my Zsh runs it via /bin/sh.

Comment: @chepner, ...wellll, that depends. If you're executing through a shell, yes, it'll do something that approximates the right thing. If it's an `execv()` call from `find`, `xargs`, or another non-shell program used to execute a shebang-less program, then the user will just get an error.

Comment: Thanks for the posts/replies guys.
I am still not very clear, my intention was to learn how do I confirm what interpreter the existing shell script will run fine with? There are some scripts written already that fail in bash but run fine with ksh. So is there anyway I could see the code and identify the language/shell it is written in for?
Can anyone share some links where I could learn the differences between the codes written for ksh and bash shell.

Comment: @chepner
very nicely explained that feature belonging to ksh will only run in ksh and not in bash or vice versa. I completely get that.
Can somebody share the differences between these two? What different commands, different keywords are in each of these interpreter.